# put background with specific size and position

Tags: android, background, background-image

i'm working on an Android application and i'dd like to put a background image. my problem when i set the android:background is that the image is show on all the screen.
i'dd like to have my background on only 50 % height and wide.

thank you

Comment: change the layout values like this : 
android:layout_width="150dp"

android:layout_height="150dp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on screen size of devices. I recommend that You read about supporting multiple screen sizes:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You can also do this programmatically, but is a bad practise. To get the result You want, You have to set a layout.xml for every screen size. It is also recommended that You better put that image inside an imageView, because of a good scaling on different devices.

Comment: i put my image in an imageview and i put it in FrameLayout and it work Thank you